# Lex Program to check for comment lines

Tags: lex

Could anyone please help me in writing a LEX program to check and count comment lines in a C program. I have searched for it everywhere and failed to get the complete code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

comment lines are of the form

> %%
>   {START} {whatever symbols,alphanumerics and letters} {END}
>   %%

- START symbol can be // or /*  in C.
- END symbol is */
- If it is "//" any other symbol can follow it in the **LINE** including a second occurances of **//** (which is ignored).
- IF it is " /* " it will find the next immediate match for " */ " and all the rest of the patterns that appear in between is matched(This matching may include blank spaces,tabs ,"//" and " /* " in it)

Here is a sample code to do it

```
`   

%{
#include<stdio.h>
int c=0;
%}
START "/*"
END "*/"
SIMPLE [^*]
SPACE [ \t\n]
COMPLEX "*"[^/]
%s newstate
%%
"//"(.*[ \t]*.*)*[\n]+    {c++; fprintf(yyout," ");}
{START}                    {yymore();BEGIN newstate;}
 <newstate>{SIMPLE}        {yymore();BEGIN newstate;}
 <newstate>{COMPLEX}      {yymore();BEGIN newstate;}
 <newstate>{SPACE}        {yymore();BEGIN newstate;}
 <newstate>{END}  {c++;fprintf(yyout," ");BEGIN 0;}
%%
main()
{//program to remove comment lines
yyin=fopen("file4","r");
yyout=fopen("fileout4","w");system("cat file4");
yylex();system("cat fileout4");
printf("no.of comments=%d",c);
fclose(yyin);
fclose(yyout);
}
`
```

The input file  "file4" is below

```
/* #include <stdlib.h>


    {}.@All nonsense symbols */
//another comment
int main{}
{/**/
 printf("hello");
 /* comment inside// comment is ignored */
 //how about//this?
 /* now we /* try this */ */
 printf("COOL!!");
 return (0);
}
```

It gives the following output which is stored in "fileout4"  `

```
 int main{}
{


 printf("hello");
     */
 printf("COOL!!");
 return (0);
}
```

`

The number of comment lines in the above program is 6.

Comment: If the input is `/** 1 /** 2 **/ 3 **/` then what is your output?

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain a *boolean* variable which keeps track of whether the line you're parsing is inside a multi-line comment or not.

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
int comment_lines = 0;
bool in_comment = false;
%}

%%
"/*".*\n { in_comment = true; ++comment_lines; }
.*"*/"\n { in_comment = false; ++comment_lines; }
"//".*\n { ++comment_lines; }
.*\n { 
    if (in_comment) {
    ++comment_lines;
    } else {
    fprintf(yyout, yytext);  
    }
}

%%

int yywrap() {
    return 1;
}

int main(void) {
    printf("Enter input file: ");
    char filename[64];
    scanf("%s", filename);
    yyin = fopen(filename, "r");

    printf("Enter output file: ");
    scanf("%s", filename);
    yyout = fopen(filename, "w");

    yylex();
    printf("Number of comments: %d\n", comment_lines);
}
```

In the above code, `in_comment` is used to indicate the state of the line being analyzed. If it is in a comment, the `comment_lines` value is incremented, otherwise the text is written to an output file given by `yyout`.

**input file**

```
#include <stdio.h>

/*
 *
 * This is a multi-line comment
 *
 */

void dummy();

// main function is the entry point.
int main(void) {
    /* 
     * Here we print a message on user's 
     * console.
     */
    printf("Hello world\n");
    // That is it.
}
```

**output file** generated after lexical analysis

```
#include <stdio.h>


void dummy();

int main(void) {
    printf("Hello world\n");
}
```

```
Number of comments: 11
```

Answer (score 0):

```
%{


#undef yywrap
#define yywrap() 1
int single=0, multiline =0;
%}


%%


"//".*"\n" {printf("%s\n", yytext); single++;}
"/*".*[\n]*.*"*/" {printf("%s\n", yytext); multiline++;}
.;

%%


int main()
{
 yyin = fopen("yourfile","r");
 yylex(); //calling the rules section
 printf(" Single line comments = %d, multiline comments = %d", single, multiline);
 fclose(yyin);
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.